# Performing many tests in 1 test plan

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to perform tests on hundreds of HTTP links one after the other.

That means i want to, for instance, perform a 3 minute test with 5 users on 1 link and after that's done, do the same for the next link.

1 way to do this is to create a ThreadGroups for each link, each having a HTTPsampler and just have all of the run consecutively. But i read that that would create memory problems for the testing machine.

So what is the correct way of doing this? I really don't feel like creating and manualy running a separate TestPlan for every link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, the suggested Test Plan structure:

- Thread Group with the number of threads (virtual users) you want to simulate

  - [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) containing the list of URLs

    [image]

    - [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) configured to last 180 seconds

      [image]

      - HTTP Request sampler configured to hit the URL:

        [image]

This way you will hit 1st URL for 180 seconds then 2nd URL for 180 seconds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you have mentioned you can create single test plan instead of multiple test plans and add multiple thread groups inside it and make sure that run thread consecutively is checked.
[image]

In each thread group mention the thread count and test duration as mentioned in the example below.

[image]

Comment: Will creating hundreds of ThreadGroups (including the sampler for each one) make RAM problems? Will it use too much?

Comment: As you are not making concurrent requests by not checking 'Run threads consecutively' so it will not be a problem to RAM. Please upvote if this solves your problem.

Comment: But i need it to first run the test on 1 link, and after that is finished run a test on the next link and so on untill all links are tested. Do i not achive that by checking "Run threads consecutively". Testing all links at the same time is not an option for me.

Comment: Okay, than you will have to check the box and you can have multiple thread groups inside a single test plan.